# Determining a value of a differentiable function.

Tags: calculus

I apologize in advance if the question does not make sense. I have absolutely no idea on how to approach or start this problem. The question is:

The function $f$ is differentiable and $\int^x_0(6f(t)+4t)dt=sin(x)$ . Determine the value of $f'(\frac{\pi}{6})$.

I had the idea of plugging in $(\frac{\pi}{6})$ into $sin$, but thats just me blindly guessing, any ideas on how to start?

Answer (score 1):

Take the second derivative of both sides, or

$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\left[\dfrac{d}{dx} \int_a^x 6f(t) + 4t \ dt\right] = \dfrac{d^2}{dx^2} \sin(x)$$

To get the first "inner" derivative on the left-hand side, you use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. Then you will be able to get an expression $f'(x) = ...$ and you can then evaluate.

Comment: assuming I did the work correctly would the correct answer be 0?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. A second option would be to take only the first derivative of both sides and solve for $f(x)$. Then take the derivative of both sides of the new equation.

Answer (score 0):

Actually all you need to know is that $f$ is continuous. Differentiate both sides, on the left using the FTC, on the right by a known formula. We get

$$6f(x) + 4x = \cos x \implies f(x) = \frac{\cos x}{6} - \frac{2x}{3}.$$

Thus $f$ is differentiable, and we get $f'(x) = -(\sin x)/6 -2/3.$ Now just plug in $\pi/6.$